# Segmentation fault when I call operator new in linux mint

Tags: c++, linux

On Linux Mint, I use operator `new` to alloc memory:

```
int maxNummber = 1000000;
int* arr = new int[maxNumber];
```

when I run my code, I meet

```
flybird@flybird ~/cplusplus_study $ ./a.out 
-412179
Segmentation fault
```

when I change `maxNumber = 100`, the code runs successfully.

the result of command `free -m`:

```
flybird@flybird ~/cplusplus_study $ free -m
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2016        800       1216          0        158        359
-/+ buffers/cache:        283       1733
Swap:         2045          0       2045
```

---

[This](https://github.com/wangyangkobe/cplusplus_study/blob/master/BitMap.cpp) is the actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>
#include <string.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class GenRandomNumber;

class BitMap
{
public:
    BitMap(int n):maxNumer(n)
    {
        int length = 1 + n / BITSPERWORD;
        pData = new int[length];
        memset(pData, 0, length);
    }
    void set(int i)
    {
        pData[i>>SHIFT] |= 1<<(i & MASK); // i&MASK 相当于i%32
    }
    void clear(int i)
    {
        pData[i>>SHIFT] &= ~(1<<(i & MASK)); // i>>SHIFT 相当于 i/32
    }
    bool test(int i)
    {
        return pData[i>>SHIFT] & (1<<(i & MASK));
    }

    void sort(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        ifstream read(inputFile.c_str());
        ofstream write(outputFile.c_str());
        int temp = 0;

        while (read>>temp)
            set(temp);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumer; ++i)
        {
            if(test(i))
                write<<i<<endl;
        }
        read.close();
        write.close();
    }
    ~BitMap()
    {
        delete []pData;
        pData = NULL;
    }
private:
    int* pData;
    int maxNumer;
    enum{ SHIFT = 5, MASK = 0x1F, BITSPERWORD = 32};
};

class GenRandomNumber
{
public:
    static GenRandomNumber* genInstance()
    {
        if(!mInstance.get())
            mInstance.reset(new GenRandomNumber());
        return mInstance.get();
    }

    void generate1(string fileName, int m, int maxNumber)
    {
        ofstream outFile(fileName.c_str());
        int* arr = new int[maxNumber];
        for(int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++)
            arr[i] = i;

        int temp = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            temp = randomRange(j, maxNumber - 1);
            cout<<temp<<endl;
            swap(arr[j], arr[temp]);
        }

        copy(arr, arr + m, ostream_iterator<int>(outFile, "\n"));
        delete []arr;
        outFile.close();
    }

    void generate2(string fileName, int m, int maxNumber)
    {
        BitMap bitmap(maxNumber);
        ofstream outFile(fileName.c_str());
        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        while (count < m)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            temp = randomRange(0, maxNumber);
            cout<<temp<<endl;
            if (!bitmap.test(temp))
            {
                bitmap.set(temp);
                outFile<<temp<<endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
private:
    GenRandomNumber(){};
    GenRandomNumber(const GenRandomNumber&);
    GenRandomNumber& operator=(const GenRandomNumber&);

    int randomRange(int low, int high)
    {
        srand(clock()); // better than srand(time(NULL))
        return low + (RAND_MAX * rand() + rand()) % (high + 1 - low);;
    }

    static auto_ptr<GenRandomNumber> mInstance;
};
auto_ptr<GenRandomNumber> GenRandomNumber::mInstance;



int main()
{
    const int MAX_NUMBER = 1000000;
    GenRandomNumber *pGen = GenRandomNumber::genInstance();
    pGen->generate1("test.txt", MAX_NUMBER, MAX_NUMBER);
    BitMap bitmap(MAX_NUMBER);
    bitmap.sort("test.txt", "sort.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code by itself itself isn't likely to cause a segmentation fault, you're doing something else wrong. Show a complete compilable example. ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Do note that you've got a typo: `maxNummber/maxNumber`

Comment: no, the code run on windows is ok. when i change the value maxNumber to 100, it is ok on linux.

Comment: also can you show the result of linux command: `free -m` ?

Comment: Are you catching the exception that `new` may throw or checking that it returns a non `NULL` pointer? In other words, are you verifying that your allocation succeeds, or do you assume it does and happily continue? Because assuming is bad.

Comment: No one knows the type of the variable maxNummber. But if the type is char or short, it certainly causes problem, because 1000000 is out of bound of char or short type.

Comment: @NikBougalis i don't verify it, just assume it successfully. maybe i should to verify it after call `new`.

Comment: @lulyon it is my mistake, the type of `maxNumber` is `int`.

Comment: @BlackMamba if you're calling an operation that can fail then you need to verify the result before continuing. If the doors of an elevator open, do you check before you walk in or do you just assume the cabin is there? I check.

Comment: What does printed number(`-412179`) mean?

Comment: @BlackMamba Then I can't see anything wrong with this code, if it runs on 32 bit or 64 bit OS. The range of int is far larger than 1000000.

Comment: @lulyon it is 32 bit Linux Mint, my os run on virtual box.

Comment: I edited your post; please, prefer to insert code here instead of post link to github in comments to an answer.

Comment: The code does not compile. You need to construct the stream similar to `ofstream of(filename.c_str())`.

Comment: i compile it successfully use this `g++ -std=c++11 BitMap.cpp`. use the option `-std`.

Comment: @soon the printed number`-412179` is the result of fuction `randomRange`, i just print it.

Comment: Indeed, it appears C++11 added another contructor (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/). Its about time they did that.

Answer (score 3):

gdb already [gave you a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169003/segmentation-fault-when-i-call-operator-new-in-linux-mint/18169036?noredirect=1#comment26618264_18169036) where the error is coming from. The only place where you use `swap` is in this function:

```
void generate1(string fileName, int m, int maxNumber)
{
    ofstream outFile(fileName);
    int* arr = new int[maxNumber];
    for(int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    int temp = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        temp = randomRange(j, maxNumber - 1);
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        swap(arr[j], arr[temp]); // <----
    }

    copy(arr, arr + m, ostream_iterator<int>(outFile, "\n"));
    delete []arr;
    outFile.close();
}
```

Swapping two ints isn't likely to be the culprit, unless you give it invalid input to begin with. `arr[j]` is pretty straightforward and should be fine, but what about `arr[temp]`? `temp` is calculated here:

```
temp = randomRange(j, maxNumber - 1);
```

and `randomRange` function looks like this:

```
int randomRange(int low, int high)
{
    srand(clock()); // better than srand(time(NULL))
    return low + (RAND_MAX * rand() + rand()) % (high + 1 - low);;
}
```

I'd say this is your problem. `RAND_MAX * rand()` probably overflows and gives you big negative numbers. Hopefully it's obvious why that's not good.

Comment: @jork you are right! from the result of my code `flybird@flybird ~/cplusplus_study $ ./a.out 
-412179
Segmentation fault`; `-412179` is the result of function `randomRange()`, so my program crash.

Answer (score 1):

1,000,000 probably should not fail on a modern desktop, so I expect you are blowing up elsewhere.

To see what/where the problem is:

```
$ gdb
gdb> file ./a.out
gdb> run
<wait for crash>
gdb> bt full
```

If the allocation failed, you should see an uncaught `bad_alloc` exception.

Otherwise, please post the source code and results of the backtrace.

Comment: i got this after running gdb:
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804956c in void std::swap<int>(int&, int&) ()
`

Comment: @BlackMamba `void std::swap<int>(int&, int&)` rings a bell? How about doing what I already told you? Show the code that's actualy relevant?

Comment: @jrok I put my code on gitHub, you can access it from `https://github.com/wangyangkobe/cplusplus_study/blob/master/BitMap.cpp#L14`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `randomRange` function.

```
return low + (RAND_MAX * rand() + rand()) % (high + 1 - low);;
```

I don't know, why do you multiple `(RAND_MAX + 1)` by `rand()`(which return value between `0` and `RAND_MAX`), but it causes overflow and may be negative.

If C++11 is an option for you, I can suggest use [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). It will return a number between passed `min` and `max` values.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: i got this after running gdb: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0804956c in void std::swap<int>(int&, int&) ()`

Comment: becase the result of function `rand()` is not random, i just want to more random.

Comment: Yep, since, you got negative number from `randomRange` and trying to access negative element here: `swap(arr[j], arr[temp]);`

Comment: _"becase the result of function rand() is not random, i just want to more random"_ - Well, @BlackMamba, your program fails randomly now. Is this random enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in the code may not directly explain the segment fault, but should also draw your attention. Note that In the class BitMap, the constructor:

```
BitMap(int n):maxNumer(n)
{
    int length = 1 + n / BITSPERWORD;
    pData = new int[length];
    memset(pData, 0, length);
}
```

The third parameter of memset is meant to be the size of allocated array, not number of elements, so it should be:

```
BitMap(int n):maxNumer(n)
{
    int length = 1 + n / BITSPERWORD;
    pData = new int[length];
    memset(pData, 0, length * sizeof(int));
}
```

The original code might causes problem because only part of the allocated array is initialized to zero by memset. The remaining code might be logically wrong because class BitMap do binary operator in the member function (set, clear, test), in which all of them presume all elements of the array that pData pointed to are set to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the problems. `m` is too large and exceeds `maxNumber`. `arr[j]`, when `j=m`, exceeds the its bounds because `arr` is only `maxNumber` in size. See the info on stack frame #1: `m=1606416912, maxNumber=999999`.

By the way, a well placed assert would have alerted you to this problem (I'm a big fan of self debugging code - I hate spending time under the debugger):

```
void generate1(string fileName, int m, int maxNumber)
{
  assert(!fileName.empty());
  assert(m > 0 && maxNumber > 0);
  assert(m <= maxNumber);
  ...
}
```

And the back trace:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x000000010007eef8
std::swap<int> (__a=@0x100200000, __b=@0x10007eef8) at stl_algobase.h:99
99        __a = __b;
(gdb) bt full
#0  std::swap<int> (__a=@0x100200000, __b=@0x10007eef8) at stl_algobase.h:99
    __tmp = 0
#1  0x0000000100000ff1 in GenRandomNumber::generate1 (this=0x7fff5fbffa10, fileName=@0x100200000, m=1606416912, maxNumber=999999) at t.cpp:91
    outFile = {
  <std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >> = {
    <std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >> = {
      <std::ios_base> = {
        _vptr$ios_base = 0x7fff745bc350, 
        _M_precision = 6, 
        _M_width = 0, 
        _M_flags = 4098, 
        _M_exception = std::_S_goodbit, 
        _M_streambuf_state = std::_S_goodbit, 
        _M_callbacks = 0x0, 
        _M_word_zero = {
          _M_pword = 0x0, 
          _M_iword = 0
        }, 
        _M_local_word = {{
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, 
            _M_iword = 0
          }}, 
        _M_word_size = 8, 
        _M_word = 0x7fff5fbff910, 
        _M_ios_locale = {
          _M_impl = 0x7fff745c1880
        }
      }, 
      members of std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >: 
      _M_tie = 0x0, 
      _M_fill = 0 '\0', 
      _M_fill_init = false, 
      _M_streambuf = 0x7fff5fbff660, 
      _M_ctype = 0x7fff745c1ab0, 
      _M_num_put = 0x7fff745c1dd0, 
      _M_num_get = 0x7fff745c1dc0
    }, 
    members of std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >: 
    _vptr$basic_ostream = 0x7fff745bc328
  }, 
  members of std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >: 
  _M_filebuf = {
    <std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >> = {
      _vptr$basic_streambuf = 0x7fff745bc230, 
      _M_in_beg = 0x100803200 "", 
      _M_in_cur = 0x100803200 "", 
      _M_in_end = 0x100803200 "", 
      _M_out_beg = 0x0, 
      _M_out_cur = 0x0, 
      _M_out_end = 0x0, 
      _M_buf_locale = {
        _M_impl = 0x7fff745c1880
      }
    }, 
    members of std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >: 
    _M_lock = {
      __sig = 0, 
      __opaque = '\0' <repeats 55 times>
    }, 
    _M_file = {
      _M_cfile = 0x7fff756bf0a0, 
      _M_cfile_created = true
    }, 
    _M_mode = 48, 
    _M_state_beg = {
      __mbstate8 = '\0' <repeats 127 times>, 
      _mbstateL = 0
    }, 
    _M_state_cur = {
      __mbstate8 = '\0' <repeats 127 times>, 
      _mbstateL = 0
    }, 
    _M_state_last = {
      __mbstate8 = '\0' <repeats 127 times>, 
      _mbstateL = 0
    }, 
    _M_buf = 0x100803200 "", 
    _M_buf_size = 1024, 
    _M_buf_allocated = true, 
    _M_reading = false, 
    _M_writing = false, 
    _M_pback = 0 '\0', 
    _M_pback_cur_save = 0x0, 
    _M_pback_end_save = 0x0, 
    _M_pback_init = false, 
    _M_codecvt = 0x7fff745c1cf0, 
    _M_ext_buf = 0x0, 
    _M_ext_buf_size = 0, 
    _M_ext_next = 0x0, 
    _M_ext_end = 0x0
  }
}
#2  0x0000000100000a18 in main () at t.cpp:140
    bitmap = {
  pData = 0x7fff5fc005a8, 
  maxNumer = 17
}
    pGen = (GenRandomNumber *) 0x1001000e0
```